# Crontab is not working... Tried all possible solutions

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run an automated tasks from php script which I couldn't run. For testing purpose, I created test.php and still nothing is working.

These are the lines I executed in the flow

```
crontab -e
```

This opened nano with

```
#.............hint text were here
#.............hint text were here
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f test.php
```

then I restarted the crontab

```
sudo service cron restart
```

confirmed the cron is working using

```
pgrep cron
```

and got the result. Also

```
/usr/local/bin/php test.php
```

also gave me `Hello World` in the terminal

**Test.php**

```
!#/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

The cronjob is also confirmed by executing

```
crontab -l
```

Tried to set permissions too

```
chmod +x test.php
chmod 755 test.php
chmod 600 test.php
```

Looking for a support to make it happen. Thanks.

Comment: So why do you think the cron is not working? Try redirecting the output to a file and see if there will be `Hello World` entries. Edit the cron so that it looks like this `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f test.php > /tmp/log.log 2>&1` and after a minute check out the /tmp/log.log file.

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: usr/local/bin/php: not found

Comment: but my where php is showing usr/local/bin/php

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Used simply php and started to get the output.

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I helped even in somewhat indirect way :) OK, I'll post an answer shortly. It's weird that it didn't work with `/usr/local/bin/php` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are your crontab is working but you just don't see the output because by default cron [mails](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) the `standard` and `error` output to the owner of the cron job. So what you can do is redirect them to a file and check it out manually.
You can do that by editing the crontab entry so that it looks like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f test.php > /tmp/log.log 2>&1
```

And then in a minute you can check it out to make sure your job is actually working.
I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

As it turned out in the comments of the question there was actually an error `/bin/sh: 1: usr/local/bin/php: not found` recorded in the `log.log` file which was fixed by just using `php`

Comment: * 14 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f test.php > /tmp/new.csv 2>&1                                     Everyday at 2pm i need to generate a csv file. Is this command correct?

Comment: Nope, this will be run every minute in the 14th hour. You need to specify 0 instead of the first asterisk for the cron to be run at exactly 14:00

Comment: 0 14 * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f test.php > /tmp/new.csv 2>&1 is this correct

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following

```
*/1 * * * * [username] /usr/local/bin/php -f test.php

e.g. */1 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/php -f test.php
```

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: ubuntu: not found